# What is the form of local supersymmetry transformations in superspace?

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity, superspace-formalism

So the most general local superspace transformation generator I can write is:

$$\hat{L} = A^\mu(x,\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} + B^\alpha(x,\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}$$

With $x$ normal variables and $\theta$ grassman variables. What additional conditions on the functions $A$ and $B$ must we impose to make this a local super-space generalisation of diffeomorphisms. i.e. for this to be the generator of the symmetries of supergravity?

e.g. for this to be a simple coordinate transformation we would have, **for small $h$**: (?)

$$\hat{L} = h^{\mu}(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} + \left(\frac{\partial h^\mu(x)}{\partial x^\nu}\theta^{\beta}\sigma_{\mu\nu}^{\beta\alpha}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}$$

where in this case there is a connection between $A$ and $B$.

As this would give the correct transformations when applied to a superfield:

$$\Phi(x,\theta) = \phi(x) + \theta^{\alpha}\psi^{\alpha}(x) + \theta^{\alpha}\theta^{\beta}(\gamma^{\alpha\beta}_\mu V^\mu(x)  +...)+...$$

And futher for the special case $h(x)^{\mu} = M^{\mu\nu}x_\nu + P^\mu$ this would give the Poincare generators.

So what would $A$ and $B$ be in the general case? I'm guessing some constraint such as $B^{\alpha}(x,\theta) = \gamma^{\alpha\beta}_\mu \hat{Q}^{\beta}A^\mu(x,\theta)$ or maybe there is not constraint?.

Answer (score 1):

There are different formulations of SUGRA in superspace. Here I will describe only $\mathcal{N}=1$ $D=4$ Einstein supergravity:

1. General coordinate transformations + super Lorentz transformations in real superspace $Z^M =(x, \theta, \bar{\theta})$:

$$
Z^M \to Z^M + \lambda^M(Z)
$$

Physical fields are in supervielbeins $E_M^{\;A}(x, \theta, \bar{\theta})$ and traditional diffeomorphism group, local Lorentz and local SUSY are remaining gauge freedom in Wess-Zumino gauge.

2. General coordinate transformations in chiral superspace $z^k =(x, \theta)$ (with some additional conditions).

$$
z^k \to z^k + \lambda^k(z)
$$

Physical superfield are $H^m = Im(x)$ and traditional diffeomorphism group, local Lorentz and local SUSY are remaining gauge freedom in Wess-Zumino gauge.

I only sketch some ideas, for more details one can consult [this](https://inspirehep.net/literature/152651) article and/or [book](https://inspirehep.net/literature/485478)  by Buchbinder and Kuzenko.

Comment: Thatnks for that article I see that equation 2 in the article has the condition similar to the one I was thinking of. Which is like: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}A^\mu(x,\theta) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}B^\alpha(x,\theta)=0$